# Upstream http and https protocol under one upstream

Tags: nginx, kong

I have been trying to add two target under one upstream, one of which is on HTTP and the other one is HTTPS. I am not sure how to acheive that, I tried adding target like:  https:10.32.9.123:443 but that didn't work.

It seems like there is a limitation that the targets could either be on HTTP or HTTPS, is there a workaround to this. My kong config file looks like below:

```
_format_version: "2.1"

_transform: true

services:
- name: test-server-public
  protocol: http
  host: test-endpoint-upstream
  port: 8000
  retries: 3
  connect_timeout: 5000
  routes:
  - name: test-route
    paths:
    - /test
upstreams:
- name: test-endpoint-upstream
  targets:
  - target: target-url:8080
    weight: 999
  - target: target-https-url:443
    weight: 1
  healthchecks:
    active:
      concurrency: 2
      http_path: /
      type: http
      healthy:
        interval: 0
        successes: 1
        http_statuses:
        - 200
        - 302
      unhealthy:
        http_failures: 3
        interval: 10
        tcp_failures: 3
        timeouts: 3
        http_statuses:
        - 429
        - 404
        - 500
        - 501
        - 502
        - 503
        - 504
        - 505
    passive:
      type: http
      healthy:
        successes: 1
        http_statuses:
        - 200
        - 201
        - 202
        - 203
        - 204
        - 205
        - 206
        - 207
        - 208
        - 226
        - 300
        - 301
        - 302
        - 303
        - 304
        - 305
        - 306
        - 307
        - 308
      unhealthy:
        http_failures: 1
        tcp_failures: 1
        timeouts: 1
        http_statuses:
        - 429
        - 500
        - 503
  slots: 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

There're no workaround for that.

You should set to redirect http to https at your webserver configurations.

[This http-to-https-redirect plugin](https://github.com/dsteinkopf/kong-http-to-https-redirect) will be helpful in your case.